# Vmware installation causing Window 8.1 host applications to open help files randomly

Tags: window, virtual-machine, vmware, virtualization

I installed vmware on my Window 8.1 HP Envy x360 PC in early december. Late december I noticed it was difficult using it as help files of any application in use just keeps sprouting up. Even when there are no applications in the window help files window shows up few minutes after a restart.

I tried many suggestions online: removing HP redundant programs, Cleaning the system of malware and spyware, reviewing/disabling accessibility settings, still no luck. I later learnt from someone's comment on one forum that he noticed this happened on his pcs with vmware installedI finally had to display window key since the behaviour was as though the window key was perpetually pressed down such that typing letter "n", "e" or the "delete" key opens the help file of the program in use or those of windows.

Now with window key disabled the situation relatively better as I can read on the pc and do some programming task; but I still get the randow opening of help files when I click "n", "e" or "delete" keys (imagine how difficult it is to type in MSWord under this situation). The exception is that this doesn't occur while using Firefox.

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the behaviour was a mimicking of window shotcuts involving the window key. So to temporarily solve this (since I didn't want to uninstall vmware) was to disable window key. I found some registry script at http://johnhaller.com/useful-stuff/disable-windows-key which I used.

This helped but when using certain programs (chrome and MSWord) typing any of n, b or delete key launches the help file so I used AutoHotKey - autohotkey.com  to write lines of script to disable any SHIFT key shortcut combination